# traverse to previous rows from current row in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to traverse to previous 10 rows from current row and check if all rows has codealert_hour . If all rows has alerts then display  prev row alert else display null.

image shows sample data.

current row is id=1176.

Now it has to traverse from id 1175 to 1166 and check all alerts. Here all alerts are present (i.e no null alerts) so it should fetch prev row alert (i.e id 1175 alert= 5)  in a column of current row.

I tried using lag function but its not working.
please help.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code or data as an image. Instead, paste it into the question as **text** and [format it using Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `LAG` and also using `self join`.

Here is the example using `LAG`.

```
SELECT
    T.*,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(T.CODEALERT_HOUR) OVER(
            ORDER BY
                ID
            ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        ) = 10 THEN LAG(T.CODEALERT_HOUR, 1) OVER(
            ORDER BY
                ID
        )
    END AS PREV_ALERT
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE T;
```

Here is the example using `self join`

```
SELECT
    T1.ID,
    T1.CHANNEL,
    T1.READ_VALUE,
    T1.READ_TIME,
    T1.CODEALERT_HOUR,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(1) = 10 THEN MAX(CASE
            WHEN T2.ID = T1.ID - 1 THEN T2.CODEALERT_HOUR
        END)
    END AS PREV_ALERT
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE T1
    JOIN YOUR_TABLE T2 ON ( T2.ID BETWEEN T1.ID - 10 AND T1.ID - 1
                            AND T2.CODEALERT_HOUR IS NOT NULL )
GROUP BY
    T1.ID,
    T1.CHANNEL,
    T1.READ_VALUE,
    T1.READ_TIME,
    T1.CODEALERT_HOUR;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: i assume you assumed with the self join aproach the topicstarter data does not contain anny gaps in the ID column?

Comment: Yes, I have given solution according to sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with lag(), it's a window function which is what you need. There are quite a few steps to get to your desired result but I think the bit you're missing is how to look back over all ten rows. This line should give the number of non-null alerts in the last 10 rows.

```
COUNT(codealert_hour) OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Comment: just want to know if it will include current row or not.

Comment: The sample I've given includes the current row, but you could change it to "preceding 10 to preceding 1"

Comment: Ohh, Cool. I am not much familiar with this